# NodeJS setInterval and send data to client

Tags: node.js

I want to execute same route with `setInterval` to send data to the client. Currently I'm getting an error after 2nd interval: `Cannot set headers after they're sent to the client`.

This is the route:

```
router.get('/api/update-time', async(req, res) => {
    try {

        const users = await User.find({served: false});
        let minutes;
        let hours;
        let seconds;

        for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            users[i].appointment -= 5;
            users[i].save();
            seconds = Math.floor(users[i].appointment / 1000);
            minutes = Math.floor(users[i].appointment / 60);
            hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
        }

        setInterval(() => {
            res.json({users, hours, minutes, seconds});
        }, 5000)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

I want to send data every 5 seconds again and again. How can I do it correctly without that error happening ?

Comment: If you want to push data to a client in an interval, you will need to look at some type of socket connection.  A get request lifecycle ends when the response is sent.  Take a look at https://socket.io

Comment: @bhmahler I don't want to use socket in this app at the moment.

Comment: If you dont want to use socket you must to make your client app ping the server endpoint each 5 seconds, HTTP protocol doesnt work as you want to

Comment: you should probably just use data pooling like Marcelo suggested in client

Answer (score 0):

res.json ends the lifecycle of the request, even if it's called within an interval. To achieve what you're looking for I'd suggest not doing it within a single request. Instead perhaps some sort of scheduler, or perhaps setting the interval on the client calling the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Http is request-response protocol. You can not send response again for the same request if already fulfilled. In your case request cycle ends as soon as you call `res.json({users, hours, minutes, seconds});`

You can leverage webscoket to send realtime update to client.
Read more here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

[sokcet.io](https://socket.io/) provide easy implementation of Web socket.
If you don't want to use `Web socket` then you can set time interval at client side to get the updates

Comment: That’s not really true and misleading, the HTTP protocol does not prohibit that the server streams data in chunks to the clients. If the client can do something with that stream depends the client. Long before Ajax was a term you where already able to use `chunked` encoding to achieve something like that. Server Side Events is also based on HTTP and is a modern way to solve that. And WebSockets also utilize the HTTP protocol to initiate the connection, but used a protocol upgrade to allow bidirectional streaming.

Comment: @t.niese you are right. I have corrected the misleading words

Answer (score 0):

A request ends when you send a response.
You can use restler to again call the api after some interval.

```
  var rest = require('./restler');
   router.get('/api/update-time', async(req, res) => {
    try {

        const users = await User.find({served: false});
        let minutes;
        let hours;
        let seconds;

        for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            users[i].appointment -= 5;
            users[i].save();
            seconds = Math.floor(users[i].appointment / 1000);
            minutes = Math.floor(users[i].appointment / 60);
            hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
        }

        setInterval(() => {
         res.json({users, hours, minutes, seconds});
         rest.get(apiUrl + '/api/update-time')
        }, 5000)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```